# How to change Bokeh button label when clicked?

Tags: bokeh

For example, I have

```
button = Button(label="0", type="success")
```

When this button is selected, I would like to change the label to "1", and vice versa. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

edit: RadioButtonGroup seems to be the widget I need. It doesn't seem to have a title attribute though. How can I position text next to the widget?

Answer (score 6):

To change the label on a Button use a callback with the `.on_click`:

```
b = Button(label='0')

def changeLabel(button):
    if button.label == '0':
        button.label = '1'
    else:
        button.label = '0'

b.on_click(lambda : changeLabel(b))
```

Instead of using the lambda function you could use `global b` inside of `changeLabel`:

```
b = Button(label='0')

def changeLabel():
    if b.label == '0':
        b.label = '1'
    else:
        b.label = '0'

b.on_click(changeLabel)
```

The second one is easier to understand, but I prefer the first version. They do the same, in the end.